# combine diiferent types and sizes in a <picture> tag

Tags: html, css

I want to serve responsive images with the `<picture>` tag.

What I want to achieve is:

If the viewport is x then serve the browser "a.webp", if it doesn't support webp then serve "a.png" and
if the viewport is y then serve the browser "b.webp", if it doesn't support webp then serve "b.png".

I've tried a few approaches and they don't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 1125px) 1125px, 100vw" srcset="img/phone/happy_girl_top-phone.webp 414w, img/happy_girl_top.webp 1125w">
  <source media="(min-width: 1125px) 1125px, 100vw" srcset="img/phone/happy_girl_top-phone.png 414w, img/happy_girl_top.png 1125w">
  <img class="img-fluid" alt="top background" src="img/happy_girl_top.png">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of your `media` attributes are not valid [media queries](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/).

Here's the official HTML documentation for embedded content: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html

The syntax of a `<picture>` element should look like this:

```css
body {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/414x200 414w" 
          media="(max-width: 414px)">
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200 800w" 
          media="(max-width: 800px)">
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1150x200 1150w" 
          media="(min-width: 801px)">
  <img class="img-fluid" alt="top background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1125x200">
</picture>
```